# Composition Relationship - What if the subclass wants access to base class properties?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a User class, and the user has multiple devices, but only one can be activated in a session i.e. active device. The device should be able to access the authentication status of the user from the User class, I don't want to store that variable in the device class, as it's a property of the User and not the device, but device will only operate if the user is authenticated.

Any suggestions how I would achieve this in C++?

Comment: Add a pointer to `User` to devices?

Comment: But it isn't consistent with standard design patterns, a pointer of User in Device suggests, Device has a User, though it's the other way around. This strategy will prevent me from performing operations like switch active device (A user can have multiple devices, but he can only work with one at a time).

Comment: A plain pointer doesn't imply ownership.

Comment: Device should have a `Owner` property that gets filled with the pointer/reference of the User that holds it. Then the device can call owner.IsAuthenticated() to know the auth status.

Comment: Yes makes sense. Thanks @HolyBlackCat and Anand. The active device once created by the user, will also have a reference to the user class, enabling such checks. The user can then switch the active device which in turn will destroy the current active device object and create a new one.

Comment: No think seperation of concerns : a device should be able to work independent of its user. That way you can fully test the device class before integrating it into something more complex. User managment/roles/access is a responsibility seperate from hardware control. So "on top" of a device you should have another layer/class with a device-like interface that does the user checking before forwarding the calls to the actual device.